# Passing Multiple Anonymous Props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using the "styled-components" library to create my button component.

Currently, my styled-component setup is like so

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

const Button = (props) => {
  const btnClass = classNames("btn", {
    disabled: props.disabled === "disabled",
    [`btn--${props.type}`]: props.type,
  });

  return (
    <button className={btnClass} type="button" onClick={props.click}>
      {props.content}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

And then, I can call it like so.

```
<Button
 content="Button"
 click={handleSelect}
 type="primary"
 disabled
            />
```

I'm doing it this way, because I want to integrate styled-components with my existing style sheet. Is what I'm doing (rewriting standard html into components) considered good practice? In my opinion, it makes the code base clearer.

My main question however is, how can I make multiple props annoymous?

I'd like to pass in the button like so...

```
<Button 
 primary
 disabled
 content="Button"
 click={handleSelect}
/>
```

Comment: Integrate styled-components with your css? It sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: I need to use a base stylesheet, and I wanted to start using stylecomponents, css in js. Should this be avoided because of the prexisting stylesheet?

Comment: If you need a base stylesheet, use `GlobalStyles` instead. You can find it in sc docs.

Comment: you see this link [sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-dew-gk2id?file=/src/App.js).